# Filtering and creating a new json file

Tags: json, jq

I am fetching node data from a chef server using knife search in json format. It returns huge data which is not relevant to me.

I am saving the whole result in a file nodeinfo.json and able to print only required data, but not sure how to convert it into a new json file.

Data I am fetching

```
$ cat nodeinfo.json | jq '.rows[].automatic.fqdn'
"node1"
"node2"
"node3"
"node4"
"node5"


$ cat nodeinfo.json | jq '.rows[].normal.environment'
"PRD"
"PRD"
"PRD"
"NPR"
"NPR"

$ cat nodeinfo.json | jq '.rows[].automatic.os'
"linux"
"linux"
"linux"
"linux"
"linux"
```

What I want in my new json file

```
{
"node":{
        "Environment": "PRD",
        "Os": "linux"
    },
"node2":{
        "Environment": "PRD",
        "Os": "linux"
    },
"node3":{
        "Environment": "PRD",
        "Os": "linux"
    },
"node4":{
        "Environment": "NPR",
        "Os": "linux"
    },  
"node5":{
        "Environment": "NPR",
        "Os": "linux"
    }
}
```

nodeinfo.json snippet

```
[{
        "results": 10,
        "rows": [{
                "name": "node1",
                "chef_environment": "npr",
                "json_class": "Chef::Node",
                "automatic": {
                    "kernel": {
                        "name": "Linux",
                        "release": "3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64",
                        "version": "#1 SMP Thu Dec 12 06:44:49 EST 2019",
                        "machine": "x86_64",
                        -
                        -
                        -
                    "hostname": "hostnamevalue",
                    "machinename": "machinenamevalue",
                    "fqdn": "node1"
                    -
                    -
                    } }
               },
               "name": "node2"
               -
               -
               -
               -
            }]
}]
```

If anyone can help me in doing this, Thanks :)

Comment: post the file where you stored the fetched data

Comment: Edit an excerpt from nodeinfo.json into your question

Comment: @komatiraju032 

I have updated my question with nodeinfo.json

Comment: `"name": "node2"` is it inside the curly braces?

Comment: @komatiraju032 , It is outside, apologise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way of doing it:

```
.rows | map({(.automatic.fqdn): {Environment: .normal.environment, OS: .automatic.os}}) | add
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/SVYH5-jLGN)</sup>